# Use jaxws-rt.jar instead rt.jar

Tags: java, wildfly

I have written a small Web Service using JAXWS and Wildfly 8.1.final. So far so good.
When a try to access SOAP headers for incoming messages using something like

```
HeaderList headerList = (HeaderList)  this.context.getMessageContext().get(JAXWSProperties.INBOUND_HEADER_LIST_PROPERTY);
```

it throws a NullPointerException because of

```
headerList
```

being null. IMHO the reason is that Wildfly uses rt.jar instead of jaxws-rt.jar although I have included the jaxws-rt.jar in my WAR file.
When I run the Web Service using JBOSS 4.2.1, no error gets thrwon.

Thanks

Edmond

Comment: Do you knwo what `rt.jar` is? It is central for your Java runtime.

Comment: I do know what rt.jar is. But why can Wildfly use jaxws-rt.jar which is indeed included in the WAR file being deployed?

Comment: hi @edmond, were you able to resolve this finally? we are facing something similar at the moment, on WildFly 10.1